# Covering number estimates on closed Riemannian manifolds

Tags: co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional compact and connected Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature bounded above and below by $c,C$.  Is it possible/known how to express the external covering number of $M^n$ as a function of $c,C$, $n$, $\operatorname{diam}(M^n)$, and possibly some other numerical data associated to $(M^n,g)$?

*This must be known, but I have no idea where to look.*

---

**Definition:** For $\varepsilon>0$, the $\varepsilon$-external covering number of $M^n$, denoted by $N_{\varepsilon}(M^n)$, is the smallest number of points $p_1,\dots,p_N\in M^n$ which are $\varepsilon$-dense wrt. $(M^n,g)$'s Riemannian distance $d_g$.  That is, if $p\in M^n$ then there is some $p_i$, as above, such that
$$
d_g(p,p_i)\le \varepsilon
.
$$

Comment: For lower bound you can use the Bishop-Gromov volume comparison, not sure about an upper bound.

Comment: @DmytroYeroshkin How can this be done?  I feel that I'm missing something.  

Also, for the upper bound I found the following unpublished article but it only holds for small balls.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1529.pdf

Comment: The simplest lower bound can be achieved as follows: By Bishop-Gromov, we know that the volume of an $\epsilon$-ball in $M$ is at most the volume of an $\epsilon$-ball in the model space with constant curvature $c$. Therefore in order for $N$ $\epsilon$-balls to cover $M$, $N$ must be at least $Vol(M)$ divided by the volume of an $\epsilon$-ball in the model space.

I suspect there are ways to improve the bound by understanding how big the overlaps have to be, but I've not actually looked at the details.

Comment: @DmytroYeroshkin Thanks, the lower-bound is obvious now; thanks for the helping details.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bishop--Gromov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Gromov_inequality) gives an **upper bound** in terms of diameter $D$, lower curvature bound $c$ and dimension $n$.
The proof is the same as in [Gromov's compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_compactness_theorem_(geometry)):

Let $p_1,\dots,p_k$ be a maximal $\varepsilon$-packing of $M$;
that is, a maximal set (with respect to inclusion) of points on distance $\geqslant \varepsilon$ from each other.
In particular, the balls $B(p_i,\tfrac\varepsilon2)_M$ are disjoint;
here $B(x,r)_M$ is a ball with center $x$ and radius $r$ in $M$.

Note that $p_1,\dots,p_k$ is an $\varepsilon$-cover of $M$;
in particular, $k\geqslant N_\varepsilon M$.
By the Bishop--Gromov inequality,
$$ \frac{\mathrm{vol}\, B(p_i,\tfrac\varepsilon2)_M}{\mathrm{vol}\,M}
\geqslant \frac{\mathrm{vol}\, B(p_i,\tfrac\varepsilon2)_{\mathbb{M}^n[c]}}{\mathrm{vol}\, B(p_i,D)_{\mathbb{M}^n[c]}},$$
where $\mathbb{M}^n[c]$ denotes the $n$-dimensional model space of curvature $c$.
Since the balls $B(p_i,\tfrac\varepsilon2)_M$ are disjoint, we get
$$N_\varepsilon M\leqslant  \frac{\mathrm{vol}\, B(p_i,D)_{\mathbb{M}[c]}}{\mathrm{vol}\, B(p_i,\tfrac\varepsilon2)_{\mathbb{M}[c]}}.$$

The following **lower bound** in terms of volume and dimesnion
$$N_\varepsilon M\geqslant \frac{\mathrm{vol}\,M}{\mathrm{vol}\, B(p_i,\varepsilon)_{\mathbb{M}[c]}}.$$
is already given by Dmytro Yeroshkin in the comments.
It requires only the Bishop inequality
$$\mathrm{vol}\, B(p_i,\varepsilon)_M\leqslant \mathrm{vol}\, B(p_i,\varepsilon)_{\mathbb{M}^n[c]}.$$